# nested dictionary doubls keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
aaa={}
aaa['bbb']={'ccc':1,'ddd':2}
print(aaa.keys())
```

```
output:
dict_keys(['bbb'])
dict_keys(['bbb'])
```

Can anyone explain to me why it prints two keys? 
Is it wrong to initialize nested dictionaries like this, or where does this behaviour come from??

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzEx0ba6lgtIRasnJSWpx9pWqycnJ6tbGeqop6SkqFsZ1XIVFGXmlWgAlehlp1YWa2hq/v8PAA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: I indeed just tried on a different computer (with a different version of python i guess) and it didn't happen

Answer (score 0):

It was just a weird bug of my notebook. closing the notebook tab, shutting down the kernel and then reopening the notebook fixed it.